# Axis of Euler rotation matrix

Tags: robotics, mechanical, matrix, robot

I'm searching the way to measure rotational displacement by using Euler rotational matrix.

And I could find various information about it.

Then I've found something wrong with reference axis.

[image: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html]

In the figure C, it indicates that the reference axis of second rotation is x'-axis not x-axis.

But the matrix is,

[image: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html]

The matrix means that the reference axis is the x-axis.

For example, if we assume the point (1,0,0) is rotated in that method for (phi,theta,psi) = (45 degrees, 45 degrees, 0 degrees), we can calculate it by using those D, C matrix. Then the result is point (0.7071,-0.5,0.5). It means just what I mentioned(except sign coincidence with the first picture). The reference aixs is x-axis not x'-axis.

I'm confused because of this problem. Please let me know what is wrong.

Thank you.

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix]

Comment: There are errors in the B, C, D matrices. For example B is the same format as D, which cannot be the case if the three axes are mutually orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Maybe Wolfram Notebook's matrices are wrong. But still, the main problem has not been not solved. I added the picture. It is from Wikipedia. And it still has same problem. Those matrices mean that the reference axes are x, y, z-axis not x', y'.